# factorial of a number in python,using for loop and while loop

Tags: python

i ran the code but no output is coming

```
var =     int(input("Enter A Number"))


if(var<=0):

print("Invalid number")

product = 1


for i in range(var):

product*=var

var-=1


while(var==0):

print(product)

break
```

why it is not executing,no result is coming?

> O/P: Enter A Number 3
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Indentation affects the behaviour of code in Python. Unindented Python code is not a [mcve].

Comment: [Edit] your question and include the indentation of your original code, then someone might be able to explain how it behaves.

Comment: Please allign your code and post properly

Answer (score 1):

Indentation aside, you are seeing no result because your code *doesn't output* the result. Your test starts with `var == 3`. Then the code does `var -=1` which means it has the value `2`. The `print()` call is wrapped in a `while` loop that will print `product` forever if `var == 0`, but will do nothing otherwise, because in that case the loop is never entered. I suspect you are expected to implement the calculation two ways, one with `for` and one with `while`.